# How to create scala runnable jar using maven?

Tags: java, scala, maven

I tried to create simple scala runnable jar using maven. i am getting this error while running "Error: Could not find or load main class"
here is my command : java -jar Jar_file-name.jar
my pom.xml for review.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>ScalaProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.learn.scala.chapter1.HelloWorldScala</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

Created runnable jar using mvn clean install . could see two jars in the target directory. ScalaProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar (doesn't have classes folder) and ScalaProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar( have classes folder)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: xxxx
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.4
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_201
```

[image]

Comment: Team.. Any help

Comment: Please open the JAR file and post the content of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` here. Also take a look at what else is inside and double check that your main class exists in the right place.

Comment: @DennisHunziker : added all required informations